# CAPTCHA is not shown at Login/register form in Magento 1.7 version

Tags: magento-1.7, captcha

I followed below steps to show captcha in login and registration form. But I can't see it.

Login to backend
Go to **system > configuration > customers > customer configuration > CAPTCHA** and select your website scope

**Enable CAPTCHA on frontend** - `Yes`

Select all forms into **Form** box

In **Displaying Mode** box select `After number of attempts to login`

**Number of Unsuccessful Attempts to Login** = 0

Save Config

Go to frontend and press **Log in** link
Is there any thing else left to enable captcha in login or registration form...

Comment: try this https://magecomp.com/magento-new-recaptcha.html

Answer (score 1):

You might have the Mage_Captcha module disabled.

Go to **System > Configuration > Advanced > Disable modules output** and make sure it is not disabled.

Another thing to check is the modules configuration file:

app/etc/modules/Mage_Captcha.xml.

Make sure it is set to active: `<active>true</active>`